# sun.swing.DefaultLookup is not accesible, problema con paquete Eclipse

Tags: java

Eclipse me marca como no accesible los siguientes paquetes , `com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable` y `sun.swing.DefaultLookup` y no entiendo el por que y como puedo hacer para que vuelvan a ser visibles
[image: ERROR]

Comment: De que versión es la librería de Java que utilizas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón de que te marque eso Eclipse (y cualquier otro IDE o incluso el compilador por linea de comando) es por que no deberías usar esa clase.

¿Por que existe esa clase entonces?

Esa clase pertenece a un API interno.

La gente de Sun en su momento y la gente de Oracle ahora cuando liberan versiones de Java indican una serie de APIs públicos (clases y paquetes bien documentados) con los que esperan que uno trabaje. Por ejemplo en el caso de Swing esta bien documentado que métodos tiene la clase JFrame, en que paquete está la clase, desde que versión existen ciertos métodos y atributos y así. Cuando se liberan nuevas versiones de Java se respeta la compatibilidad hacia atrás de esas clases, es decir se extienden. Nunca se borran ni se eliminan métodos para que un programa que funcionaba con cierta versión de Java siga funcionando con versiones superiores.

Ahora bien, además de las APIS publicas también en las liberaciones se generan APIs internas. Clases y paquetes que sirven de apoyo y que son susceptibles de ser borradas en liberaciones futuras de Java.

Al igual que como te ha ocurrido, hay muchas personas que llegan a utilizar APIs internas en sus programas (por error o adrede, esto por que a final de cuentas la clase/paquete esta disponible y puede usarse). Para evitar esto desde Java 9 se introdujo una nueva tecnología de modulos que provoca que ahora ni por error se pueda utilizar una API interna.

Comment: Muy buena respuesa, aunque comentar que parece que solo aplicable a `sun.swing.DefaultLookup` (de hecho si el OP busca la clase por Google llega a [esta página](http://srcrr.com/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/sun/swing/DefaultLookup.html) que le dice `WARNING: While this class is public, it should not be treated as public API and its API may change in incompatable ways between dot dot releases and even patch releases. You should not rely on this class even existing.`

Comment: La otra (`com.sun.istack.internal.Nullable`) parece ser parte de un `com.sun.istack » istack-commons-runtime` que no sé muy bien de dónde sale ni qué hace.

Comment: Hola @SJuan76 En realidad hay muchas APIS internas por ejemplo el paquete com.sun.rowset también pertenece a esta categoría lo mismo la clase com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities y así varias otras.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta corrigiendo la indicación de que desde Java 10 hay modularidad colocando que es desde Java 9. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias , solucionado!